# Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys - Only in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API and I get this warning in only Safari:

Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys

and I also get the popup "This page can't load Google Maps correctly"

In Chrome it's fine and working, but not in incognito mode.

Here is how I am adding the library:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=(MY_KEY)&libraries=places&ver=5.4.2'></script>
```

Comment: 2 things might have happened 1. You had cache. Clear it and it would start working or you have blocked the ip by mistake.

Comment: How do I check if the ip is blocked

Comment: Clearing cache did not work

Comment: In the keys section in the cloud console, go to credentials and check the restrictions portion.

Comment: Also try copying the key again and paste it to check the results.

Comment: why do you have 2 versions specified on your script tag? `v=3` is very old and has [been deleted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#documentation-for-the-api-versions) and I also don't know what `ver=5.4.2` is for. I suggest that you remove both of these version parameters so that will get you the weekly version by default. For your reference, you can the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).